# Joomla - getModules returns empty array

Tags: joomla

I'm trying to use getModules() to return an array of all of the modules assigned to a module position.

I appear to be doing it correctly according to the [documentation](https://docs.joomla.org/JModuleHelper/getModules), but it is not working.

(print_r added for debugging purposes)

```
   <?php 

    jimport( 'joomla.application.module.helper' );
    $mymodules = JModuleHelper::getModules( 'floorplans' );

    print_r( $mymodules );


    $moduleList = '';       
    foreach ($mymodules as $mymodule) {
        $moduleList = $moduleList . '"' . $mymodule[0]['title'] . '",';
    }
    $moduleList = rtrim($moduleList , ',');
    echo $moduleList ;
    ?>
```

This only gets me an empty array.

Notes:

- This is Joomla 3.
- "floorplans" is defined in the template xml (though I do not actually
  display it in the template).
- There are modules published and assigned to the "floorplans" module
  position.

What could be going wrong? What else should I check?

Comment: Open this  file 'libraries\cms\module\helper.php', go to line number 369 and print the $query. This will shows you the query running.

Comment: That didn't produce any output when loading the page in question (an admin page)